# UIButton with pan gesture and press method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to give a `UIButton` different features depending on if it is pressed and released once, or held down (ideally for 1.5 sec) and moved around the screen. I am using this code at the moment:

```
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(open:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]

    panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
    [panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [button addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

-(IBAction)open:(id)sender {}

-(void)move:(id)sender{}
```

`move:` works fine, but `open:` doesn't.

Comment: why dont you use `UIView` it gives you finer control over such custom gestures...

Comment: What difference would that make? `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`... This code works fine here btw, though you should use `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` instead of `UIControlEventTouchDown` if you want the event to trigger when the touch is released.

Comment: Omz your answer works fine! If you want to answer yourself I can vote you up

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use button's drag event, like

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(wasDragged:withEvent:) 
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
```

You can look at this link: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/11/draggable-buttons-labels/

you can put a flag in move mehod, when enter touch up method, you check if the button has moved, to decide to trigger open related logic

```
#define BUTTON_DRAGGED_TAG -100
#define BUTTON_DEFAULT_TAG 0

- (void)onButtonTouchUpInside:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (button.tag != BUTTON_DRAGGED_TAG)
    {
        //doOpen
    }

    button.tag = BUTTON_DEFAULT_TAG;
}

- (void)onButtonTouchUpOutside:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    button.tag = BUTTON_DEFAULT_TAG;
 }

- (void)onButtonTouchCancel:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    button.tag = BUTTON_DEFAULT_TAG;
}

- (void)onButtonDraged:(UIButton *)button withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    button.tag = BUTTON_DRAGGED_TAG;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this, let me know if it works for you:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizeTapGesture:)];
    tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView    = NO;
    tapGesture.delegate                = self;
    [tapGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
    [self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
    self.tapGesture = tapGesture;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if (touch.view == self.button)
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)didRecognizeTapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"GESTURE ENDED");
    }
}

- (void)didPressButton:(UIButton*)sender
{
    NSLog(@"BUTTON TOUCH UP INSIDE");
}
```